# Citus: shard_size is empty

Tags: citus

Citus 11.1.5
select * from citus_shards return many rows, but field shard_size is empty.

I expect that field shard_size from citus_shards table are not be empty.
I need to calculate size of all shards.

Answer (score 0):

It should print the size; this is my output on 11.2.

```
├─[ RECORD 3 ]─────┼───────────────────────────────┤
│ table_name       │ citus.demo_distributed        │
│ shardid          │ 102016                        │
│ shard_name       │ citus.demo_distributed_102016 │
│ citus_table_type │ distributed                   │
│ colocation_id    │ 1                             │
│ **shard_size**   │ **8192**                      │
```

Comment: May be it is some bag on 11.1.5:
"shardid","shard_size"
102014,NULL
102014,NULL
102014,NULL

Comment: I could reproduce this on 11.1 branch, but once I inserted rows, I do see the non-zero size.

select * from citus_shard_sizes();
┌──────────────────────────┬──────┐
│        table_name        │ size │
├──────────────────────────┼──────┤
│ citus.local_table_102013 │    0 │
│                          │    0 │
│ citus.dist_table_102009  │ 8192 │
│ citus.dist_table_102011  │ 8192 │
│ citus.ref_table_102012   │    0 │
│                          │    0 │
│ citus.dist_table_102008  │ 8192 │
│ citus.dist_table_102010  │ 8192 │
└──────────────────────────┴──────┘

Comment: select * from citus_shards;


table_name  │ shardid │        shard_name        │ citus_table_type │ colocation_id │ nodename  │ nodeport │ shard_size 
│ ref_table   │  102012 │ citus.ref_table_102012   │ reference        │             2 │ 127.0.0.1 │    10000 │          0 │
│ ref_table   │  102012 │ citus.ref_table_102012   │ reference        │             2 │ 127.0.0.1 │    11000 │         **0** │

**insert into ref_table values(1,0);**

│ ref_table   │  102012 │ citus.ref_table_102012   │ reference        │             2 │ 127.0.0.1 │    10000 │       **8192** │

Comment: While the query is running I see:
WARNING:  stack depth limit exceeded
HINT:  Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.

Comment: Which query are you referring to, select * from citus_shards is causing stackoverflow?